# web2py: sending email: lost connection after EHLO from localhost

Tags: linux, email, smtp, centos, web2py

I'm trying to send email in web2py using the postfix server on Centos. I can send it successfully using the gmail SMTP server, but when I change the settings to:

```
mail.settings.server='127.0.0.1:25'
mail.settings.login = 'user:pass'
```

no email gets delivered. I checked the logs and I see this:

```
postfix/smtpd[31521]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
postfix/smtpd[31521]: lost connection after EHLO from localhost[127.0.0.1]
postfix/smtpd[31521]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

I am able to send email successfully using the local mail command. I am new to linux, so please bear with me.

Comment: have you verified the postfix smtp server is running independently of web2py?  e.g. http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/send-mail-through-smtp-using-telnet/

Comment: Yup, that worked. It sent the email.

Comment: and you're using authentication off port 25?  if not, set mail.settings.login = None

Comment: I tried both with & without authentication and get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

depending on your version of web2py try setting
  mail.settings.tls = False

Comment: I know this is old, but this worked for me and thought I would share this with others.